# How to setup non-dev Corda Network?

Tags: corda

I'm trying to setup a non-dev Corda network, I have seen document from:

https://docs.corda.r3.com/setting-up-a-corda-network.html

However, it trust is a test network, so anyone can tell me how to setup the non-dev network for utilizing in real life?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The process for creating your own non-dev network is documented here: https://docs.corda.net/head/permissioning.html#creating-your-own-compatibility-zone.